# Overriding inline style after element is loaded with Thickbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, inline, thickbox

I have a form and there's a thickbox binded to an `<a>` element on it. When you click the element it loads an URL inside the box and runs some script. Due to restraints of the platform I'm working on, I have no access to the scripts, to the thickbox.js or to the HTML that's being loaded. All I can do is write my own styles and scripts.

The problem is that something is giving several inline styles to `#TB_window` after it's loaded. Take a look:

```
<div id="TB_window" style="position: fixed; z-index: 10002; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -315px; width: 630px; margin-top: -220px; display: block; ">
```

My whole problem lies on the width, I need to override that style. I tried to bind a click event to the `<a>`, like this:

```
('a#btnReferAFriend').click(function(){
    if('#TB_title.length'){
        $('#TB_window').css('width','400px');
        alert($#TB_window.css('width');
    } else {
        alert('Wrong');
    }
});
```

The result of that is script is an alert displaying "400px". But just after this my style is overriden by the inline ones. I don't know exactly what's happening, I think another script is running somewhere, maybe a modified `thickbox.js`?

What should I do to override the inline styles *after* they've been applied?

Comment: use f12 (inspecty element) and use magnify icon to search where is the applied style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following style:

```
#TB_window { width:400px !important; }
```

This should override the width that is found in the inline style.

Comment: This actually worked, thanks a lot! I didn't know `!important` could override inline styles. Is this the standard behavior of `!important`? Thanks, anyway!

Comment: Yeah, !important will override a style regardless where it is placed. Here's more information for you. http://www.impressivewebs.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-important-css-declaration/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the inline style to force it to respect your own declarations:

```
$('#TB_window').removeAttr('style')
```